# Application failed to start because it could not find or load the Qt platform plugin "xcb" in

Tags: c++, qt, qt-creator, qt5.6

I am using Qtcreator to build and run my program. Build is success but while running I am getting the following error

```
This application failed to start because it could not find or load the Qt platform plugin "xcb"
Reinstalling the application may fix this problem.
```

I am using Qt5.6.1-1 and creator 4.0.3 based on Qt 5.6.1

Tried by exporting path
export QT_PLUGIN_PATH=/home/SysUser/Development/Qt5.6.1-1/plugins/platforms
Still its not working

I am having Qt5.12.6 also installed but this app need Qt 5.6.1 so I renamed  Qt5.12.6 folder.

Any lights will be a great help

Comment: What do you mean by "so I renamed Qt5.12.6 folder"? Renamed it from "Qt5.12.6" to "Qt5.6.1"?

Comment: This might help: "To obtain diagnostic information from Qt, about each plugin it tries to load, use the QT_DEBUG_PLUGINS environment variable. Set this variable to a non-zero value in the environment where your application is launched." https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/deployment-plugins.html

Comment: @ChristianHalaszovich That would be crazy. I do not think he did this... :)

Comment: I renamed Qt5.12.6 to Qt5.12.6_Temp and used Qt5.6.1 which is already installed

Comment: I think the path should be `export QT_PLUGIN_PATH=/home/SysUser/Development/Qt5.6.1-1/plugins`, isnt it?

Comment: Yes Peter
I gave the same path through terminal then launched Qtcreatur usign same terminal

Comment: @HiFilethebestfilemanager Well, I've seen people do things like this (and worse) ;-)